# How do I access a variable from my markup page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-slider

This is going to sound pretty basic but I have to ask anyways.I have a jQuery range slider, I have labels that show what step the slider handle is at. So I added this variable

```
var myData = $("slider-range").slider("option", "min");
```

In my codebehind page I'm trying to access that variable and I can't figure it out.

The code for the slider is,

```
$(function () {

    $("#slider-range-Monday").slider({

        create: function (e, ui) {
            var c = $(this).children('.ui-slider-handle')
            $(c[0]).append('<a class="ui-slider-label">0</a>');
            $(c[1]).append('<a class="ui-slider-label">24</a>');
        },

              range: true,

              min: 0,

              max: 24,

              values: [0, 24],

              animate: 'slow',



              slide: function (event, ui) {
                  $('.ui-slider-label', this)[0].innerHTML = ui.values[0];
                  $('.ui-slider-label', this)[1].innerHTML = ui.values[1];

                  $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

              }

          });

          $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +

            " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

          var myData = $("slider-range").slider("option", "min");

});
```

I need to be able to access the sliders values and I don't know how. I thought about adding a hidden label to the sliders labels and I don't know how to do that later. If this has been asked before please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to process those values server-side? If so, you need to send an Ajax request.

Comment: I'm not sure actually. Before I was able to use asp labels for labels on the slider handles, but I lost that code when my laptop crashed. When the slider moves the labels follow the handle and show the position, so when the position is set that's when I need to be able to access the handle position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hidden field

```
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" runat="server" />
```

Set its value like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=hiddenField.ClientID%>").val(myData )
});
```

Comment: @user2970223, Do you want slider value? And delete older comments so that we can continue interactiong

Comment: Yes, I was asked to create 7 range sliders in jquery and 7 spinners. They need to be able to access the number that the handle falls onto I.e 8 and they need to access that so they can add those values to a database.

Comment: I got it figured out. I'm doing this in the sliders slide function.... $("Label1").text(ui.values[0]);... Now my next hurdle is getting the spinners value